# Is this 95% Confidence Interval Based on the Corrected Correlation or Uncorrected Correlation in Meta-Analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, confidence-interval, meta-analysis

My questions are:

- Is the 95% CI in a meta-analysis based on the uncorrected correlation or corrected correlation?
- Can a 95% CI have an upper limit that is *smaller* than the lower limit?

Context:

I'm trying to understand the results of a meta-analysis paper. There are two things that I understand about 95% CIs (please correct me if I am wrong)

1. if a correlation falls outside of the 95% CI, then it is non-significant.
2. in a 95% CI, the value of the Upper Limit (CIu) is always higher than the value of the Lower Limit (CIl)

In their table of results, two correlations are reported - an uncorrected correlation (*r*) and a corrected correlation (*p-hat*). When the author reports the finding, they refer to p-hat. But some of the p-hat values fall OUTSIDE of the 95% CI, yet the author says that their findings support their hypothesis of a positive relationship. Hence the confusion.

Comment: What do the authors mean by a "corrected" correlation?

Comment: here is what they noted in the Analysis Section, "effect sizes were corrected individually for unreliability in both the antecedent measures and the cohesion measures, utilizing alpha coefficients. When alpha coefficients were not provided, mean reliabilities of similar measures were imputed in order to make corrections"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot tell what the authors did without reading the paper and I suspect from bitter experience we will be no further forward if we do have it.

A confidence interval has to cover a range of values so the upper limit will be greater than the lower limit and in general the point estimate will fall within that range although there are rare circumstances where that does not happen.

If the confidence interval does not include the null value, which for correlations is zero, then it would usually mean that the point estimate was significantly different from zero although there are some situations where the assumption underlying confidence interval construction differ from the significance test.

It may well be that p-hat falls outside the interval for r but it should not fall outside the interval for p-hat.